# AsyncStorage is not returning the callback

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am using `redux-persist` in a react native project, that runs just fine in a broad number of devices **except Android 7**. I am trying to debug the problem on why my local storage is nor persisting and found this:

The following code executes inside React Native component lifecycle's

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    attachObservables(store)
    setInterval(async () => {
      console.log('Inside setInterval')
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
      console.log('inside the getAllKeys')
      data.forEach(async k => {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(k)
        console.group(k)
        console.log(value)
        console.groupEnd()
      })
    }, 3000)
  }
```

Code after 'Inside setInterval' is never called. It only runs once if outside the setInterval. If I call once the code *outside* the setInterval it appears to run just fine. I also tried callback format vs async / await version but it does not seem to matter.

Same problem I had using firebase js library (callbacks never return after the first one). I am now looking for alternatives to workaround the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you try using interaction manager or time mixin ? [timers link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html) for me AsyncStorage working fine when I use getItem().then..

Comment: It does work using interaction manager, but not with time mixin

Comment: I think interval not working might be because time needed for asyncStorage longer than 3s.. thus it keep reloading but not finished.. might be you can experimenting using longer interval.. Sometimes my AsyncStorage take 3-7 seconds to loads picture uri

Comment: Then it should fulfill in an async way, the thing is that it is never fulfilling

Comment: I con confirm this bug in my Android 7. Works on first load, but if the App is minimized or reloaded by shaking the device, the Promise is not resolved nor fullfilled (and the same for the callback). @jsdario , did you report this bug on github?

Comment: Just see your report, thnks.

Comment: You and all others collaborating on fixing this are so welcome! I am not experiencing this anymore on simulators over v0.53, anyhow others have also reported, so the issue is still open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of React Native 0.51 in some Android versions, the runtime can get blocked by other native modules, impeding the resolution of the mentioned methods.

It can be fixed via https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14101#issuecomment-345563563, ensuring this methods use a free thread from the thread pool.

A PR has been submitted and I hope that will be released in future versions. If you want it to use this fix right now, it is available here https://github.com/netbeast/react-native

EDIT: 
I am not experiencing this anymore on real devices over react-native@0.53, anyhow others have also reported, so the issue is still open.